# append rows in CSV using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have piece of code like below.

```
$month = Get-Date -Format "yyyy_MM"
$csv_location = "C:\brivo\csv\" + $month + ".csv"
if (!(Test-Path $csv_location))
{
    $newcsv = {} | Select "Time","Name","Surname","Email","Telephone","Company","Department","Address","Postcode","City","State","Country" | Export-Csv $csv_location -NoTypeInformation
}

ForEach($line in $lines){
    Try
    {
        $line = $line.Trim()
        $file = "C:\brivo\json\" + $line
        $data = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json
    
        $timestamp = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

        $userline = $timestamp,$data.name,$data.surname,$data.email,$data.telephone,$data.company_name,$data.department,$data.address,$data.postcode,$data.city,$data.state,$data.country
        $userline | out-file $csv_location -Append
    }
    Catch [Exception]
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception | format-list -force
    }
}
```

where first part is creating csv file if not exist with headers. and in second part **$lines** is file names like **123.json, 456.json...** and all those json files has content like below.

```
{
    "name": "kamal",
    "sur_name": "wewetwe",
    "email": "asdasd@gmail.com",
    "telephone": "311234544567",
    "company_name": "",
    "department": "",
    "address": "qwe",
    "postcode": "1234 ad",
    "city": "qwe",
    "state": "GR",
    "country": "NL"
}
```

what I want is to append all this json data to csv file. I have tried like above but it adds data in 1st column itself.

Comment: look to this page first page on google https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-convert-json-file-to-csv-file-using-powershell

Comment: this works with one json file to csv. I have to add many json files to one csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Don't try to initialize your CSV file *without data* using [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv), because that won't work**:

  - The dummy object with `$null` property values created by [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) results not in just in a *header* row, but invariably also in a *data row* representing the `$null` values, which end up as empty strings; in other words, you'll get a data row that looks like this: `,,,,,,,,,,,`
  - Instead, make sure that the *properties* of the objects *representing data rows* you pass to `Export-Csv` are *named for the desired CSV columns*.
- **Don't try to construct your data rows as an *array* of values to save to the CSV file *as plain text***;<sup>[1]</sup> instead, construct a `[pscustomobject]` for each data row, which `Export-Csv` automatically converts to a data row, with the property names serving as column names (as you attempted with your header row).

  - As the code below shows, you can construct an object in each iteration and pipe it to a *single* `Export-Csv` call for efficiency.

    - Use the `-Encoding` parameter to control the output character encoding as needed; notably, in Windows PowerShell the default encoding is ASCII(!).
  - `-Append` is still used in that single call, because it looks like you want to append to a preexisting target file, if present.
  - **Important**:

    - The *first* object sent to `Export-Csv` locks in the list of columns and their names based on *its* properties; subsequent objects are expected to have the same set of properties (or a meaningful subset).
    - Similarly, when appending to a preexisting CSV file with `-Append`, the objects to append must match the existing columns, although you can override this requirement with `-Force`.

```sh
$month = Get-Date -Format "yyyy_MM"
$csv_location = "C:\brivo\csv\" + $month + ".csv"

# $lines is assumed to be an array of your input JSON file names.
$lines | ForEach-Object {
    Try
    {
        $file = "C:\brivo\json\" + $_.Trim()
        $data = Get-Content -ErrorAction Stop -Raw $file |
                  ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction Stop
    
        # Construct and output an object with the desired values and the
        # properties named for the desired CSV columns.
        [pscustomobject] @{
          Time = Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
          Name = $data.name
          Surname = $data.surname
          Email = $data.email
          Telephone = $data.telephone
          Company = $data.company_name
          Department = $data.department
          Address = $data.address
          Postcode = $data.postcode
          City = $data.city
          State = $data.state
          Country = $data.country
        }

      }
    Catch
    {
        Write-Host $_.Exception | format-list -force
    }
} | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Append $csv_location
```

---

<sup>[1] If you send an *array* of values to `Out-File`, each value becomes its *own line* in the output file. While you could address that with `$userline -join ','`, such plain-text processing is brittle, because values with *embedded* `,` chars. wouldn't be handled correctly.</sup>

Comment: can i export this csv to two different locations? $csv_location and $other_csv_location

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya, in theory you could `... | ConvertTo-Csv | Tee-Object -FilePath $other_csv_location | Set-Content $csv_location`, but that only allows you to control the character encoding with `Set-Content`, not with `Tee-Object`, which on Windows PowerShell will create "Unicode" files (UTF-16LE). Therefore, I suggest simply calling `Copy-Item $csv_location $ohter_csv_location` after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

**this is some example **

```
 #add your json files on temp dir
    $a= Get-ChildItem C:\Temp\PatchingServer*
    foreach($g in $a){
        $j=gc $g
        $f=$j| ConvertFrom-Json    
        $obj=New-Object PSobject
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty "Port" $f.Port       
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty "ApplicationName" $f.ApplicationName
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty "MaintenanceWindow" $f.MaintenanceWindow
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty "BusinessUnit" $f.BusinessUnit
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty "AppOwner"  $f.AppOwner
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty "AppID"    $f.AppID
        $obj | Add-Member Noteproperty "Location" $f.Location
        $obj | export-csv C:\Temp\Patching.csv  -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
```

Comment: it is giving me errors